# Add new button with autocomplete list at bottom of the suggestion list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

[image]

I Want to add new button at the bottom of suggestion list in autocomplete custom template. can you help me if this feature is already available or how can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS material design - Chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips)